# Horizontal Progress Bar iPhone Class?

Tags: iphone

Is there an iPhone Class which implements a nice looking progress bar which is a bit taller and more customizable than the built-in one? I'm looking for something that would look like this:

http://pixomania.net/wp-content/php/progress/pexample.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to alter the `UIProgressView`, but you could use a [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This will allow you to set images for the two ends and the thumb image with `- setMaximumTrackImage:forState:`, `- setMinimumTrackImage:forState:`, and `- setThumbImage:forState:` respectively.

You can then update the slider value with `– setValue:animated:` and get the visualization that you want.